# Alert message is navigated to other page when used with redirect_back :fallback_location in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

I am having a destroy method in employees controller as:

```
# DELETE /employees/1
def destroy
  if @employee.destroy
    redirect_to employees_url, notice: ‘Employee record was successfully destroyed.'
  else
    alert = ['Employee record could not be destroyed']
    alert += @employee.errors.full_messages.map{ |s| "#{s}." } #because of some reason
    alert = alert.join(' ')
    redirect_back :fallback_location => @employee, :alert => alert
  end
end
```

> Output alert message: Employee record could not be destroyed because of some other
>   reason

It is redirecting to same show page but when I am navigating to some other page, the same alert message is persisted wherever I navigate.
I tried modifying it using flash[:alert], flash.now.alert and etc but no luck. 
Could you please suggest how to fix this from controller end?

Answer (score 1):

[Rails redirect_to API](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Redirecting.html#method-i-redirect_to) documents an undesirable scenario that might happen when you are making a request with something other than a GET or POST (in this case using a DELETE)

> If you are using XHR requests other than GET or POST and redirecting after the request then some browsers will follow the redirect using the original request method. This may lead to undesirable behavior such as a double DELETE. To work around this you can return a 303 See Other status code which will be followed using a GET request.

The solution is to try adding a status on your options array in the `redirect_back`

```
redirect_back fallback_location: @employee, alert: alert, status: 303
```